# How to correctly pass video into Shoutem HTML component?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I want to show video in HTML component, but when I pass a string

```
let body = '<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJJpnplTBeM" poster="https://img.youtube.com/vi/vJJpnplTBeM/maxresdefault.jpg"></video>';
```

to the component

```
return (<ScrollView>
    <Html body={body} style={{}}/>
</ScrollView>);
```

it show an error `No suitable image URL loader found for (null)`.

How to correctly pass video into Shoutem HTML Component?

Answer (score 0):

Shoutem's video component [does what you're trying to do](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/components/Video/Video.js), you could simply [use it](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/video) instead.

```
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myvideo' }}
  poster={'https://mypic.png'}
  height={200}
  width={300}
/>
```

Comment: Of course I know how to insert Video with Shoutem, but I want to insert video with HTML component.

Comment: The question is not actual now, I’am use another component

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/components/Video/Video.js), that I also linked above to see how our Video component does it.